# Getting PHP namespaces working for AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, namespaces

I am trying to setup the AWS sdk for php on my local environment.
I am neither Composer nor PHAR.I am just extracting it from the [zip](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html#installing-via-zip) file and adding the extracted folder to my `c:\wamp\www\` directory.I created a index.php file to access the sdk classes.The index file is

```
  <?php
    define('AWS_KEY', '');
    define('AWS_SECRET_KEY', '');
    define('HOST', 'http://www.example.com');

 // require the AWS SDK for PHP library
 require 'build/aws-autoloader.php';
 //require_once '';
 use Aws\S3\S3Client;
 //require_once('src/Aws/S3/S3Client.php');

 // Establish connection with DreamObjects with an S3 client.
 $client = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
'base_url' => HOST,
'key'      => AWS_KEY,
'secret'   => AWS_SECRET_KEY
));

?>
```

The autoloader.php is below.Here I updated the path for UniversalClassLoader.php file as I had to download it from git.In the `AWS_FILE_PREFIX` variable I updated the root path for all classes.

```
 require_once 'UniversalClassLoader.php';

 if (!defined('AWS_FILE_PREFIX')) {
 define('AWS_FILE_PREFIX', 'C:\wamp\www\awssdk\src\Aws');
 }

 $classLoader = new UniversalClassLoader();
 $classLoader->registerNamespaces(array(
   'Aws'      => AWS_FILE_PREFIX,
   'Guzzle'   => AWS_FILE_PREFIX,
   'Symfony'  => AWS_FILE_PREFIX,
   'Doctrine' => AWS_FILE_PREFIX,
   'Psr'      => AWS_FILE_PREFIX,
   'Monolog'  => AWS_FILE_PREFIX
 ));

 $classLoader->register();

 return $classLoader;
```

BUt I keep getting the error class not found for `S3Client` class in the **index.php** file.I cross checked the path using `require` and it finds the class.
Can someone help me point what am I doing wrong here ? I have no prior experience of using namespaces or autoloaders and cannot debug this issue.

Comment: I am facing the same issue... Could you get the solution??